# PHP Contact Form return code

Tags: php, contact-form

I have the following PHP script that runs when a send button is clicked.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
$to = 'shanaywork@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit') {               
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit']) {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
```

?>

I am using MAMP to host the website locally. The problem occurs when the send button is hit, instead of the email being sent a page with the code is shown.

What is wrong in my code and how may I fix it?

Thank You.

Comment: A page with what code is shown?

Comment: `if ($_POST['submit') {` -> `if ($_POST['submit']) {` maybe? Also your `elseif` doesn't make sense

Comment: Probably your php code isn't excuted. Try to run this script: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If it doesn't output a page with your local php configuration, start with configuring apache.

Comment: @putvande no, it's not a duplicate. The problem here is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {               
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
    $to = 'shanaywork@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hello';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
} else{
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

There are lots of error in your code

1. The condition in `if` and in `else if` are same so the `else if` condition never execute.
2. While checking submit from post value use `isset($_POST['NAME'])`.